# Evento a partir da escolha da opção do radio jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Estou tendo dificuldades para implantar a seguinte função e gostaria da ajuda de vocês;

Tenho um `input` com duas opções de `radio`.
caso o usuario selecione o valor_1, o `jQuery` remove a classe `hidden` de uma `div` e adiciona em outra, caso ele selecione o valor_2 o ocorre o mesmo, porém com outra `div`. O problema é que nunca me deparei com essa situação. Abraço!

```css
 .hidden{
   display:none;
   }
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_contabeis">
 <br/>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="demo_radio" id="demo_radio" value="atendeu" checked>A elaboração dos Demonstrativos Contábeis e de Gestão <strong>Atendeu</strong> os Parâmetros da mencionada Instrução.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="demo_radio" id="demo_radio_n" value="n_atendeu">A elaboração dos Demonstrativos Contábeis e de Gestão <strong>Não Atendeu</strong> os Parâmetros da mencionada Instrução.
    </label>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="controle">
    <textarea id="demonstrativocontabeis" name="demonstrativocontabeis" class="form-control" rows="10">
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="controle hidden">
    <textarea id="demonstrativocontabeis_n" name="demonstrativocontabeis_n" class="form-control hidden" rows="10">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

1 - adicionei duas classes para o controle

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab_contabeis">
    <br/>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="demo_radio" id="demo_radio" value="atendeu" checked>A elaboração dos Demonstrativos Contábeis e de Gestão <strong>Atendeu</strong> os Parâmetros da mencionada Instrução.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="demo_radio" id="demo_radio_n" value="n_atendeu">A elaboração dos Demonstrativos Contábeis e de Gestão <strong>Não Atendeu</strong> os Parâmetros da mencionada Instrução.</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="controle atendeu">
        <textarea id="demonstrativocontabeis" name="demonstrativocontabeis" class="form-control" rows="10">atendeu</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="controle nao-atendeu hidden">
        <textarea id="demonstrativocontabeis_n" name="demonstrativocontabeis_n" class="form-control hidden" rows="10">não atendeu</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

2 - o seu css

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

3 - o jquery para controlar

```
//adiciona o evento para identificar quando foi alterado
jQuery('input[name="demo_radio"]').on("change", function () {
    //remove a class qeu esconde os itens
    jQuery(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");
    //verifica qual o item foi selecionado e coloca a classe hidden no outro
    if (jQuery(this).val() == "atendeu") {
        jQuery(".nao-atendeu").addClass("hidden");
    } else if (jQuery(this).val() == "n_atendeu") {
        jQuery(".atendeu").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

o link para o exemplo funcionando está [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/r6f45uch/1/)